# Error in using prewhiten function in r

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to use prewhiten function(TSA package) in my time series forecasting model. But i am getting below error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to
an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

I have no clue about this error. For example if i try to run example given in TSA package pdf(page number 50). I get the same error. Below is the code quoted from the same pdf:

```
   data(milk)
   data(electricity)
   milk.electricity=ts.intersect(milk,log(electricity))
   plot(milk.electricity,yax.flip=TRUE,main='')
   ccf(as.numeric(milk.electricity[,1]),as.numeric(milk.electricity[,2]),
   main='milk & electricity',ylab='CCF')
   me.dif=ts.intersect(diff(diff(milk,12)),diff(diff(log(electricity),12)))
   prewhiten(as.numeric(me.dif[,1]),as.numeric(me.dif[,2]),
   ,ylab='CCF')
```

Can anyone please help me with this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code above works for me.

However, I suspect that you have loaded another package before running this piece of code. In particular, if I load **dplyr** first

```
library(dplyr)
```

then I can reproduce your error.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I had loaded DataCombine package. 'dplyr' was imported by 'DataCombine. After detaching, it is working fine for me. Thanks a lot!